# String's replace all is replacing none

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have the following code:

```
System.out.println("Trace: #" +"2");
System.out.println(rv); 
        rv.replaceAll("$t",sTAB);
System.out.println("Trace: #" +"3");
System.out.println(rv);
```

The rv and sTAB are of type String.  And sTAB has a value of a tab character.  The output is as follows:

```
Trace: #2
is$thi$t
Trace: #3
is$thi$t
```

But I expect:

```
Trace: #2
is$thi$t
Trace: #3
is{tab}hi{tab}
```

Of course with {tab} being actual tab characters. Can you explain what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a **regular expression** and **returns** the replaced `String`.

`$` is a regular expression [meta character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that matches the end of a line.

Try using:

```
rv = rv.replaceAll("\\$t", sTAB);
```

Comment: rv.replaceAll("\$t",sTAB); gives an "illegal escape character" error when compiling.  rv.replaceAll("\\$t",sTAB); compiles but gives the same result as before.

Comment: @Kevin Did you reassign the return value of `replaceAll()` to `rv`? I just tested this and it works correctly.

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot rv=rv.rep... but that did not work either but that plus adding the two slashes did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Java `String`s are immutable.  Once you have a `String` it won't change.  `replaceAll` actually returns a new string with the replacements.

You should do

```
rv = rv.replaceAll("$t",sTAB);
```

Also note that `replaceAll` takes a regular expression. You should probably escape the `$`.

```
rv = rv.replaceAll("\\$t", sTAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

No?

```
rv = rv.replaceAll("$t",sTAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the string `rv = rv.replaceAll("$t",sTAB);`